# Как записать данные в фаил в "нечитаемом" виде?

Tags: файлы, java

Здравствуйте) Мне для игры (громко сказано) надо сделать сохранение/загрузку) Сохранять данные буду в фаил, и читать с него соответственно. Как записать данные в фаил так, чтобы пользователь не смог прочитать содержимое (квакозябры всякие), а программа при чтении с этого файла получила бы корректные (=правельно опозноваемые) данные?
Если вы знаете как по-другому организовать сохранение/загрузку напишите пожалуйста и разъесните)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XOR на строку, а саму строку передавать или в конце или в начале, реализовать просто, а разгадать уже не так просто как если просто XOR
В каждом случае строка будет разная что еще более усложняет обратную расшифровку злоумышленнику.
Только длина строки и ее местонахождение будет одинаковым и известно автору.

Answer (score 3):

Это не тот случай, где требуется настоящее шифрование (обычно в играх так и есть), поэтому наиболее адекватным вариантом будет простое и быстрое [XOR-шифрование](http://kriptografea.narod.ru/XOR.html).

Answer (score 2):

А в чём проблема? Чтобы просто не прочитал человек, можно в бинарном виде записать. Можете сериализацию применить ( так кстати и будет парвильнее, для сохранения состояния ), можете применить функции кодирования и декодирования, написать свои, вариантов уйма!

Answer (score 1):

Ответ прост. Заюзать шифрование. Например по ключу.
Лично мне нравится алгоритм AES. 
Вот пример шифрования:

```
/* Derive the key, given password and salt. */
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 256);
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
/* Encrypt the message. */
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal("Hello, World!".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Расшифровка тут:

```
/* Decrypt the message, given derived key and initialization vector. */
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
String plaintext = new String(cipher.doFinal(ciphertext), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(plaintext);
```

Взято отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption

Comment: Обычная проблема: а ключ куда засунуть?

Comment: @Barmaley, в рессурсы, если не принципиально, в реестр. все что находится на компе, можно принципиально перехватить в расшифрованном виде перед использованием. можно критически важные данные для логики авторизации и сейвов, хранить на сервере.